# Problema con un puntero a tipo struct

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

Mi problema es el siguiente: Quiero implementar un TAD que permita recorrer una colección de datos de tipo `string`, ingresando valores al final y en la cabecera .h tengo la declaración:

```
typedef rep_string *coleccion;
```

En el archivo .cpp mi `rep_string` es un struct con 3 campos: `inicio` (para reiniciar el recorrido), `actual` (para indicar el `string` apuntado) y `final` (para agregar los datos)

```
struct nodo {
char *frase
nodo *sig;
};

struct rep_string {
nodo *inicio;
nodo *actual;
nodo *final;
};
```

Mi pregunta es si la declaración:

```
coleccion aux = new rep_string;
```

y posteriormente, cuando la colección tenga elementos, la llamada:

```
aux->inicio->frase
```

son correctas.

Comment: ¿ Lo has intentado ? ¿ El compilador te ha dado algún error ?

Comment: La compilación me daba errores, ahora no tengo los mensajes de error a mano, pero me quedó la duda si habría algún problema con la estructura.

Comment: En principio lo que pones es (o debería ser) correcto. Para darte una respuesta definitiva deberías poner un ejemplo de uso y preguntar sobre el mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mi pregunta es si la declaración:
>
> ```
> coleccion aux = new rep_string;
> ```
>
> y posteriormente, cuando la colección tenga elementos, la llamada:
>
> ```
> aux->inicio->frase
> ```

Lo son. Pero esos usos no son (en mi opinión) adecuados.

#### El alias oculta el tipo subyacente.

Normalmente cuando en C++ definimos una variable de tipo puntero, le añadimos el asterisco:

```
tipo_de_datos *puntero;
//            ~ <--- ¡Esto es un puntero!
```

Pero podemos *ocultar* el puntero en un alias:

```
typedef tipo_de_datos * otro_tipo;
otro_tipo dato;
//        ~~~~ <--- Aunque sea puntero, ¡no lo sabemos de un vistazo!
```

En tu caso, debido a este uso del alias, no es evidente que `coleccion` sea un puntero y el código se hace confuso:

```
// Como? Guardamos el resultado de new en algo que NO PARECE UN PUNTERO?
coleccion aux = new rep_string;
// Un momento! Si aux no parece un puntero, por qué usa el operador flecha?
aux->inicio->frase
```

El uso de un alias para un tipo no debería restar claridad al código si no sumarla.

#### Propuesta.

No uses alias:

```
rep_string *aux = new rep_string;
// rellenar datos....
aux->inicio->frase
```

En las líneas anteriores se ve claramente que `aux` es un puntero a `rep_string`, si te da pereza escribir dos veces `rep_string` puedes usar la deducción automática de tipos:

```
auto aux = new rep_string;
// rellenar datos....
aux->inicio->frase
```

Sabemos que `new` siempre devuelve punteros, así que consultando la definición de `aux` vemos en seguida que es un puntero.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct 
{
    const char* frase;//value
    Node* next;//para apuntar al siguiente

}Node;

typedef struct 
{
    Node *inicio; 
    Node *actual;//aqui estariamos usando al nodo que nos hemos creado
    Node *final;
}Rep_String;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //la declaracion esta bien paraece, solo que no manejo bien por la forma que lo declaras
te recomendaria aprender un poco mas
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creo que a ti tampoco te vendría mal repasar algun manual de C++... `typedef struct { } Node`  es algo propio de C... no de C++, donde no es para nada necesario.